# Mongoose find all documents but exclude some objects because of slow loading time

Tags: mongoose

So I have documents that I'm getting from database with the function findAll, the problem is that just some fields I'm using, and I would like to reduce the loading time by fetching all documents but excluding some elements from it with Mongoose or MONGO.

So for example This is the long document, and I don't need to show the images, so I would like to find all documents but not fetch images, like the following example:

My function right now:

```js
"name": "Coffe",
"images": [a lot of photos],
"description: "...",
"price": 12
```

What I need:

```js
"name": "Coffe",
"images": \[a lot of photos\],
"description: "...",
"price": 12`` ` ``
```

I didn't found a way until now, the loading time is to long sadly